# How to get values from dynamic radiogroup android?

Tags: android, radio-group

Hi i created dynamic radiogroup with radiobutton.Now i want to get values from dynamic radiogroup. Below is my code

```
final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
            rg.setId(questionNo);

            RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[answers.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < answers.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject answerObject = answers.getJSONObject(i);
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                rb[i].setText(answerObject.getString("AnswerValue"));
                rb[i].setId(answerObject.getInt("AnswerId"));

                rg.addView(rb[i]);
            }



rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                        int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        Log.i("ID", String.valueOf(selectedId));

                    }
                });
```

Button click event

```
submit_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1){
                int id= rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = rg.findViewById(id);
                int radioId = rg.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(radioId);
                String selection = (String) btn.getText();
                Log.i("selection", selection);

            }
            }
        });
```

I am getting only last index of the radio group.

Comment: @codeMagic  how to get all the selected values from radiogroup ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194515/android-get-value-of-the-selected-radio-button

Comment: @codeMagic hi i am getting last value only

Comment: Because they are all in a single `RadioGroup` so you can only have one selected at a time. You need to put them in separate groups or use checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, But this may help someone else

While creating your Dynamic Radiobutton Group, Create a parent layout(Linear layout or Relative Layout)

All radio groups will be the child of that Layout and all radio button will be a child of the specific radio group.

> Creating No of Dynamic Radio Group

- Create all Dynamic radio group in a parent layout
- Add all radio button to a group
- Add all radio group to the parent layout

  ```
      public RadioButton[] rb;
      public RadioGroup grp;
      public LinearLayout layoutmain;             //Parent layout

  for(int i=0;i<qus.size();i++)                   //No of Questions
  {

      rb = new RadioButton[size];
      grp = new RadioGroup(this);

      grp.setId(a+qus.get(i).qusetionId);

      for(int j=0;j<qus.get(i).choices.size();j++)    //No of Radio button in radio group
      {

          rb[j] = new RadioButton(this);
          rb[j].setText(qus.get(i).choices.get(j).getChoiceText());
          grp.addView(rb[j]);                         // adding button to group

      }
      layoutmain.addView(grp);                        // adding group to layout
  }
  ```

> Retrieve All selected button task

- From parent, layout get all child
- Find all radio group using the child Instance
- Create an object for that radio group
- using that object get the selected radio button

  ```
  Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

          for(int i=0;i<layoutmain.getChildCount();i++)  //From the parent layout (Linear Layout) get the child
          {
              View child = layoutmain.getChildAt(i);  

              if(child instanceof RadioGroup)     //Check weather its RadioGroup using its INSTANCE
              {
                  RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) child; //create a RadioButton for each group
                  int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); // get the selected button

                      RadioButton radiochecked = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                      Log.e("Radio",radiochecked.getText().toString());   //from the button get the selected text

              }
          }
      } });
  ```